# [powershell]what I can't add the user name in the log file?

Tags: powershell

```
while ($true) {if (-not([String]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-NetTCPConnection -RemoteAddress 10.86.178.10).OwningProcess))) {Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -RemoteAddress 10.86.178.10).OwningProcess >> \\fuobomdt01.ap.win.int.kn\Wechat\10.200.0.34\$env:computername.log;break}}
```

above powershell script works ,but I add the username at the log file then system is show warning.

```
while ($true) {if (-not([String]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-NetTCPConnection -RemoteAddress 10.86.178.10).OwningProcess))) {Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -RemoteAddress 10.86.178.10).OwningProcess >> \\fuobomdt01.ap.win.int.kn\Wechat\10.200.0.34\$env:computername"_"((gcim cim_computersystem).username).split("\\")[1].log;break}}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryHMm.png)

may I have your advise? thanks.

below file name is my expecting.

## CNFUODC13Z8Y2_jack.ou.log

Comment: If you do not have a connection to 10.86.178.10 I think you would get this error.

Comment: Please post your error message as *text* rather than a screenshot - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3156906 for why…

Comment: Distribute your script over multiple lines. That will give you a narrowed error of which part actually fails. Wild guess: `gcim cim_computersystem` returns `$Null`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you wouldn't want the output filename to contain YOUR current computername, but the name of the remote computer instead.
Also, just writing out all the OwningProcess numbers to a file seems rather pointless to me.. so why not output a Csv file instead where you can add multiple properties about the process in a structured way?

Something like this perhaps:

```
$computer = '10.86.178.10'
$logPath  = '\\fuobomdt01.ap.win.int.kn\Wechat\10.200.0.34'
while ($true) {
    $tcpConnection = Get-NetTCPConnection -RemoteAddress $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($tcpConnection) {
        $computerSystem = Get-CimInstance –ComputerName $computer –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
        $currentUser    = ($computerSystem.UserName -split '\\')[-1]
        $computerName   = $computerSystem.Name
        $outFile        = Join-Path -Path $logPath -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}.csv' -f $computerName, $currentUser)
        # here you specify the interesting properties to store in the output csv file
        $tcpConnection | Select-Object State, LocalPort, OwningProcess,
                         @{Name = 'ProcessName'; Expression = { (Get-Process -ComputerName $computer -Id $_.OwningProcess).ProcessName }} | 
                         Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
        break
    }
}
```